# How to increase text area size of summnote field in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, summernote, laravel-backpack

I am using laravel backpack as a crud and i'm creating a laravel admin panel with it. I need to use the summernote wysiwyg field and there is a options field attribute with laravel backpack and I am trying to input the minheight option for summer note however it does not add it to the intiatlaztion properly

```
    $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'desc',
        'type' => 'summernote',
        'label' => "feature description",
        'options' => [
            'minheight: 300'
        ]
    ]);
```

[image: laravel crud]

as you can see it does not increase the mineheight does anyone have any ideas?

i have a work around but it requires me to edit vendor files which it not something i want to have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Place this script below your page to modify size and other characteristics of summernote editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
          height: 250,
          disableResizeEditor: true // This is optional if you want to remove resize
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your rows and cols size in the attributes array !

```
$this->crud->addField([
     'name' => 'desc',
     'type' => 'textarea',
     'label' => "feature description",
     'attributes' => [
         'rows' => 20,
         'cols' => 20
     ]
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your options property wrong.

```
'options' => [
    'minheight: 300'
]
```

While actually it should be:

```
'options' => [
    'minheight' => 300
]
```

See the difference?

You can use summernote API like this:

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'desc',
    'type' => 'summernote',
    'label' => "feature description",
    'options' => [
        'minheight' => 300,
        'height' => 400
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->crud->addField([
  // Summernote
   'name' => 'description',
   'label' => 'Описание',
   'type' => 'summernote',
   'options' => [
     'placeholder'=> 'Содержание статьи',
     'height'=> 500,
                       'toolbar'=>[

                           ['style', ['style']],
                           ['font', ['bold']], // show only bold button
                           ['color', ['color']],
                           ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                           ['table', ['table']],
                           ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
                           ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
   ],
 ]
]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).